# Call to undefined relationship [companies] on model [App\Models\Announcement]. How can I solve this

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables : announcements and companies. company_id is a foreign key on announcement table.

I have controller set up like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Announcement;
use App\Models\Company;

class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{
public function upcomingIssues()
    {
        $announcement = Announcement::orderBy('id','desc')->with('companies')->get();

        return view('pages.upcoming-issues',compact('announcement'));

    }
}
```

Announcement model is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Announcement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'announcements';
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }

    // Usage: $announcement->company
    public function getCompanyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->companies->where('id','company_id')->get();
    }
}
```

Company Model is follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';

    public function announcement()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Announcement::class, 'company_id');
    }
}
```

And Finally View table as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Company</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($announcement as $announce)
        <tr>
          <th>{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
          <td>{{ $announce->company }}</td>     
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

when I try to access this page I get following message
"

> Call to undefined relationship [companies] on model
> [App\Models\Announcement].

"

Comment: Only one question per post please. This will help others find the exact problem and its solution. If you have a new problem that doesn't have an answer on Stack Overflow yet, please ask a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to two ways to solve this issue.One is to change relationship name in  Announcement model

```
public function company()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
}
```

to

```
public function companies()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
}
```

or keep relationship name as it is and change in controller

```
public function upcomingIssues()
{
        $announcement = Announcement::orderBy('id','desc')->with('companies')->get();

        return view('pages.upcoming-issues',compact('announcement'));

}
```

to

```
public function upcomingIssues()
{
        $announcement = Announcement::orderBy('id','desc')->with('company')->get();

        return view('pages.upcoming-issues',compact('announcement'));

}
```

and also if you are using company as relationship name then change

```
public function getCompanyAttribute()
{
        return $this->companies->where('id','company_id')->get();
}
```

to

```
public function getCompanyAttribute()
{
        return $this->company->where('id','company_id')->get();
}
```

Comment: One more question.
This is from view:
@foreach($announcement as $announce)
   {{ $announce->company }}
@endforeach.

Next it is from Model:
public function getCompanyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->companies->where('id','company_id')->get();
    }

Now my question is how can I pull company_id from view to model here?